# How to load a multiline recordset into an Access form with VBA

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, recordset

I'm runing a query (which is returning the correct data) but how can I loop the recordset and add each line in the form with VBA? Because it's currently adding the last line repeatedly.

```
Private Sub buscarReservasFio()
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblReservasFio WHERE fk_solicitacao = " & "'" & arrParameters(0) & "'"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

If rs.BOF Or rs.EOF Then
    'to-do insert
    MsgBox ("Insert")
Else
    Do Until rs.EOF
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        Me.ds_funcao = rs.Fields("ds_funcao").Value
        Me.fk_titulo = rs.Fields("fk_titulo").Value
        Me.nr_cor = rs.Fields("nr_cor").Value
        Me.nr_peso = rs.Fields("nr_peso").Value
        Me.dt_liberacao = rs.Fields("dt_liberacao").Value
        Me.dt_baixa = rs.Fields("dt_baixa").Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

rs.Close
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: Table and Form]

Comment: P.S.: I need to loop the recordset loading each line, because one of the fields (Me.nr_peso) will be recalculated with VBA then displayed to user manually edit or confirm the information.

Comment: This makes no sense. A form must have a RecordSource and controls bound to fields to display multiple records.

Comment: And I don't see any calculation of nr_peso - when exactly does this occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, form is bound to table but your code is populating UNBOUND controls. That's the only way I can replicate your output - which should be expected. The reason multiple rows of same data show is because controls (BOUND or UNBOUND) repeat for each record and since there is only one set of controls, the same data shows in UNBOUND controls for all rows - last record from recordset loop. Step debug and watch data change on form. The GoToRecord action is meaningless because no data is input to BOUND controls. The result is same without that line.

In order to display multiple records from table, bind controls to fields. Then, options to modify nr_peso field with new calculated value when form first opens:

1. run an UPDATE action SQL
2. open a recordset of form's RecordsetClone and loop through that recordset and change value of nr_peso field - changes in RecordsetClone will immediately reflect in the form
3. code physically moves to each record on form and modifies field value

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware of this method. It should work perfectcly and it's way simpler.